# Como colocar una foto al lado de la otra con CSS

Tags: php, css

espero se encuentren bien.

Tengo la siguiente consulta y la estoy generando en un PDF:

```
$fotos=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM gastos");

while($crowmatetw = mysqli_fetch_array($fotos)){
    

$tabla.="   
<table border='0' CELLPADDING=10 CELLSPACING=0>
";
if(empty($crowmatetw['soporte']))
{
$tabla.="
<tr>
<td style='text-align:center;'>Sin Soporte</td>
</tr>";
}else{
$tabla.="
<tr>
<td style='text-align:center;'><img src='$crowmatetw[soporte]' style='width:250px;height:350px;'></td>
</tr>";
}
$tabla.="
</table>";
}
```

La variable '$crowmatetw[soporte]' imprime la foto que este registrada y por medio de un while traigo todas las fotos.

El problema que tengo es que cuando le agrego un estilo a la foto para que salga una al lado de la otra se imprimen todas las fotos hacia la derecha quedando muchas fotos fuera del PDF sin poder ver.

De que forma podría hacer que las fotos se impriman una al lado de la otra pero de dos en dos por fila.

Actualmente se ve así el PDF con las fotos, pero la idea es que salga la foto una al lado de la otra de dos en dos.

Que me aconsejan hacer?

Cualquier ayuda me podría ser de gran utilidad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Veo que estás imprimiento un <tr> en el else, si se imprime una por vez, te saldrá una abajo de la otra, saca el  <tr> y deja solo los <td>, podrías además, colocar un width: 100% a la imágen para que no se desborde si es mas grande que 250px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es añadir un contador para saber cuántas columnas tiene la línea actual. Tu código quedaría algo así:

```
$fotos=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM gastos");

$tabla.="<table border='0' CELLPADDING=10 CELLSPACING=0>";
$counter = 0;

while($crowmatetw = mysqli_fetch_array($fotos)){
    if ($counter === 0) {
        $tabla.="<tr>";
    }

    $counter++;
    $tabla.="<td style='text-align:center;'>"
        . (empty($crowmatetw['soporte'])
            ? "Sin Soporte"
            : "<img src='$crowmatetw[soporte]' style='width:250px;height:350px;'>")
        . "</td>";

    if ($counter === 2) {
        $tabla.="</tr>";
        $counter = 0;
    }
}

// En caso de que las fotos sean impares, añade una celda vacía
if ($counter !== 0) {
    $tabla.="<td></td></tr>";
}

$tabla.="</table>";
```